# UpdateAttributes does not work

Tags: php, sphinx

I have a problem with UpdateAttributes, it seem to not work for me.
When I issue:

```
$ret = $sphinx->UpdateAttributes ( "products", array ("status"), array(506607786 => array(10)) );
```

it returns 1, but search still returns status as old value for this.

When I try

```
$ret = $sphinx->UpdateAttributes ( "products", array ("status", "image_id"), array(506607786 => array(10, 6666)) );
```

it returns 0 (false)

Does this function even work ?

Ok I have found (sphinx docs are ugly) that when issuing updateAtrributes() from PHP app then I will not see the results in search command line. However one problem still
exist - I'm not able to update 2 attributes in one updateAtrributes() - seperatly they are fine - any clues why ?

Answer (score 0):

When `UpdateAttributes` returns `0` (not false) it does not mean it didn't work, what it means is it didn't find anything to update, basically no updates commited. A return of `-1` actually means this function did not work.

Make sure that `506607786` is actually an `id` in your Sphinx index and that `products` is the name of your index.

To make the question more helpful you can provide an example row from your table, preferrably the one used in this function defined as `506607786`. You cna also provide a full set of your code to make it easier.

As a side note: `UpdateAttributes` does not act like a realtime index. You will need to filter on these attributes specifically in your query in order for sphinx to take their new values into consideration.

Comment: The thing is that: $ret = $sphinx->UpdateAttributes ( "products", array ("status"), array(506607786 => array(0)) ); <- works - return 1 |  $ret = $sphinx->UpdateAttributes ( "products", array ("image_id"), array(506607786 => array(90942)) ); <- this one also works and return 1, but => $ret = $sphinx->UpdateAttributes ( "products", array ( "image_id", "status"), array(506607786 => array(90942, 2)) ); does not work

Comment: @user630198 I must be honest I am not sure what your problem is with multi attributes but have you made sure image_id exists? Is image_id a foreign key?

Comment: @user630198 One thing I can think is that your are getting these attributes through some other source that might be giving them to you as a string or a float or whatever? Have you tried casting the values as ints?

Comment: Problem is I can not update two attributes at the same time, when doing one attribute per UpdateAttributes then it works, otherwise it does not work, image_id and status are just int rows in certain table, that's all - they are correct as I have written that singular update works for them. Can't figure it out why it does not work with 2 attributes

Comment: @user630198 So you have tried each attribute separately? hmm I would prolly ask the sphinx user group on their site, I cannt see any syntax errors there.